# How do I make this text display on the screen on the click of a button?

Tags: button, text, printing, p5.js

```
let img
let img2
let img3;
let img4
let img5


function preload(){
  img = loadImage("Barb1.png");
  img2 = loadImage("Barb2.png");
  img3 = loadImage("Barb3.png");
  img4 = loadImage("Barb4.png");
  img5 = loadImage("Barb5.png");
}
  


function setup() {
  createCanvas(1500, 1500);
  scene = 1; 
  
  ButtonA = createButton("A. GOOD");
  ButtonA.position(20,640);
  ButtonA.size(100,50)
  ButtonA.mouseClicked(correct0);
          
 
  

  ButtonB = createButton("B. PINEAPPLE");
  ButtonB.position(20,700);
  ButtonB.size(100,50)
  ButtonB.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  
 
  ButtonC = createButton("C. PLEASE KILL ME");
  ButtonC.position(20,760);
  ButtonC.size(100,50)
  ButtonC.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  
  

  ButtonD = createButton("A. BAD");
  ButtonD.position(20,640);
  ButtonD.size(100,50)
  ButtonD.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  ButtonD.hide(); 
  

  ButtonE = createButton("B. PINEAPPLE");
  ButtonE.position(20,700);
  ButtonE.size(100,50)
  ButtonE.mouseClicked(correct1);
  ButtonE.hide(); 
  
 
  ButtonF = createButton("C. PLEASE KILL ME");
  ButtonF.position(20,760);
  ButtonF.size(100,50)
  ButtonF.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  ButtonF.hide(); 
  
   ButtonG = createButton("1. Delicious");
  ButtonG.position(20,640);
  ButtonG.size(100,50)
   ButtonG.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  ButtonG.hide(); 
 
  

  ButtonH = createButton("2. Rainy");
  ButtonH.position(20,700);
  ButtonH.size(100,50)
  ButtonH.mouseClicked(correct2);
  ButtonH.hide(); 
  
 
  ButtonI = createButton("3. Red!");
  ButtonI.position(20,760);
  ButtonI.size(100,50)
  ButtonI.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  ButtonI.hide(); 
  
   ButtonJ = createButton("1. My name is __!");
  ButtonJ.position(20,640);
  ButtonJ.size(100,50)
   ButtonJ.mouseClicked(correct3);
  ButtonJ.hide(); 
  
 
  

  ButtonK = createButton("2. Carpe Diem!");
  ButtonK.position(20,700);
  ButtonK.size(100,50)
   ButtonK.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  ButtonK.hide(); 
  
 
  ButtonL = createButton("3. I don't know yet, what's yours?");
  ButtonL.position(20,760);
  ButtonL.size(100,50)
   ButtonL.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  ButtonL.hide(); 
  
  
  ButtonM = createButton("1. Goodbye Barb!");
  ButtonM.position(20,640);
  ButtonM.size(100,50)
   ButtonM.mouseClicked(correct4);
  ButtonM.hide(); 
  
   ButtonN = createButton("2. Hello. Barb!");
  ButtonN.position(20,700);
  ButtonN.size(100,50)
   ButtonN.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  ButtonN.hide(); 
  
   ButtonO = createButton("1. THANK THE LORD, IT'S OVER!");
  ButtonO.position(20,760);
  ButtonO.size(100,50)
   ButtonO.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  ButtonO.hide(); 
  
   homebutton = createButton("HOME");
  homebutton.position(395, 405);
  homebutton.size(150,150);
  homebutton.mousePressed(goHome);
  homebutton.hide();
}
  
function correct0(){
  print("Barb says,'Good job!' Hold left click and '2' to advance'")

}
function correct1(){
  print("Barb says, 'Good job!' Hold left click and '3' to advance'");
}
function correct2(){
  print("Barb says, 'Good job!' Hold left click and '4' to advance'");
}
function correct3(){
  print("Barb says, 'Good job!' Hold left click and '5' to advance'");
}
function correct4(){
  print("Barb says, 'Good job!' Hold left click and '6' to advance'");
}

function incorrect(){
  print("Barb says, 'Hmm...that response to my question does not make sense, please try again!''");
}

function goHome(){
    window.open('https://editor.p5js.org/PragyaKumari2/sketches/3fhigQjLg');  
  }

function draw() {
  background(100,200,300);
          if(scene ==1){
            image(img,0,0,800,600)
  text("Read the options out loud and choose your answer, make sure to check the console for BARB's reply!", 10, 620)
  textSize(19);
              if(keyIsPressed){
                if(key ==2){
                  scene =2
                  ButtonA.remove();
                  ButtonB.remove();
                  ButtonC.remove();
                  ButtonD.show();
                   ButtonE.show();
                   ButtonF.show();
                  
                  
          }
             
        }
    }


  
  if(scene ==2){
  image(img2,0,0,800,600)
  text("Read the options loudly and choose your answer!", 50, 620)
  textSize(20);
  

  
      if(keyIsPressed){
                if(key ==3){
                  scene =3
                  ButtonD.remove();
                  ButtonE.remove();
                  ButtonF.remove();
                  ButtonG.show();
                  ButtonH.show();
                  ButtonI.show();
          }
             
        }
 
  }
  if(scene == 3){
  image(img3,0,0,800,600)
  text("Read the options loudly and choose your answer!", 50, 620)
  textSize(20);

  
      if(keyIsPressed){
                if(key ==4){
                  scene =4
                  ButtonG.remove();
                  ButtonH.remove();
                  ButtonI.remove();
                ButtonJ.show();
                  ButtonK.show();
                  ButtonL.show();
          }
             
        }
    
  }
 if(scene ==4){
   image(img4,0,0,800,600)
   text("Read the options loudly and choose your answer!", 50, 620)
  textSize(20);
 
  
      if(keyIsPressed){
                if(key ==5){
                  scene =5
                  ButtonJ.remove();
                  ButtonK.remove();
                  ButtonL.remove();
                  ButtonM.show();
                  ButtonN.show();
                  ButtonO.show();
                }
             
        }
   
 }
  if(scene == 5){
    image(img5, 0,0, 800,600)
   
    text("Read the options loudly and choose your answer!", 50, 620)
  textSize(20);
 
      if(keyIsPressed){
                if(key ==6){
                  scene =6
                  ButtonM.remove();
                  ButtonN.remove();
                  ButtonO.remove();
                  homebutton.show();
                }             
  }
  }
  
  if(scene == 6){
        text("Thanks a lot for playing! Make sure to practice speaking!", 200, 375)
  textSize(20);
     
    
  }
  
  
}
```

I am able to print to the main console terminal, but I do not know how to print to the display screen. Ive tried using the text function, but it does not appear at all. I am also not that familiar with p5js, so I am stuck on this problem. Is there a problem with the function? Do I need to do something else to output the text? Is it an issue with the scene function I implemented?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a global variable `msg` to keep the message you want to show to the user. So after next calling of the `draw` function, you can show it by `text` function if it has any value.
Also your code needs to set `textAlign`.

```js
let img;
let img2;
let img3;
let img4;
let img5;

let msg;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage("Barb1.png");
  img2 = loadImage("Barb2.png");
  img3 = loadImage("Barb3.png");
  img4 = loadImage("Barb4.png");
  img5 = loadImage("Barb5.png");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1500, 1500);
  scene = 1;

  ButtonA = createButton("A. GOOD");
  ButtonA.position(20, 640);
  ButtonA.size(100, 50);
  ButtonA.mouseClicked(correct0);

  ButtonB = createButton("B. PINEAPPLE");
  ButtonB.position(20, 700);
  ButtonB.size(100, 50);
  ButtonB.mouseClicked(incorrect);

  ButtonC = createButton("C. PLEASE KILL ME");
  ButtonC.position(20, 760);
  ButtonC.size(100, 50);
  ButtonC.mouseClicked(incorrect);

  ButtonD = createButton("A. BAD");
  ButtonD.position(20, 640);
  ButtonD.size(100, 50);
  ButtonD.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  ButtonD.hide();

  ButtonE = createButton("B. PINEAPPLE");
  ButtonE.position(20, 700);
  ButtonE.size(100, 50);
  ButtonE.mouseClicked(correct1);
  ButtonE.hide();

  ButtonF = createButton("C. PLEASE KILL ME");
  ButtonF.position(20, 760);
  ButtonF.size(100, 50);
  ButtonF.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  ButtonF.hide();

  ButtonG = createButton("1. Delicious");
  ButtonG.position(20, 640);
  ButtonG.size(100, 50);
  ButtonG.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  ButtonG.hide();

  ButtonH = createButton("2. Rainy");
  ButtonH.position(20, 700);
  ButtonH.size(100, 50);
  ButtonH.mouseClicked(correct2);
  ButtonH.hide();

  ButtonI = createButton("3. Red!");
  ButtonI.position(20, 760);
  ButtonI.size(100, 50);
  ButtonI.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  ButtonI.hide();

  ButtonJ = createButton("1. My name is __!");
  ButtonJ.position(20, 640);
  ButtonJ.size(100, 50);
  ButtonJ.mouseClicked(correct3);
  ButtonJ.hide();

  ButtonK = createButton("2. Carpe Diem!");
  ButtonK.position(20, 700);
  ButtonK.size(100, 50);
  ButtonK.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  ButtonK.hide();

  ButtonL = createButton("3. I don't know yet, what's yours?");
  ButtonL.position(20, 760);
  ButtonL.size(100, 50);
  ButtonL.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  ButtonL.hide();

  ButtonM = createButton("1. Goodbye Barb!");
  ButtonM.position(20, 640);
  ButtonM.size(100, 50);
  ButtonM.mouseClicked(correct4);
  ButtonM.hide();

  ButtonN = createButton("2. Hello. Barb!");
  ButtonN.position(20, 700);
  ButtonN.size(100, 50);
  ButtonN.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  ButtonN.hide();

  ButtonO = createButton("1. THANK THE LORD, IT'S OVER!");
  ButtonO.position(20, 760);
  ButtonO.size(100, 50);
  ButtonO.mouseClicked(incorrect);
  ButtonO.hide();
  homebutton = createButton("HOME");
  homebutton.position(395, 405);
  homebutton.size(150, 150);
  homebutton.mousePressed(goHome);
  homebutton.hide();
}

function correct0() {
  msg = "Barb says,'Good job!' Hold left click and '2' to advance'";
}
function correct1() {
  msg = "Barb says, 'Good job!' Hold left click and '3' to advance'";
}
function correct2() {
  msg = "Barb says, 'Good job!' Hold left click and '4' to advance'";
}
function correct3() {
  msg = "Barb says, 'Good job!' Hold left click and '5' to advance'";
}
function correct4() {
  msg = "Barb says, 'Good job!' Hold left click and '6' to advance'";
}

function incorrect() {
  msg =
    "Barb says, 'Hmm...that response to my question does not make sense, please try again!''";
}

function goHome() {
  window.open("https://editor.p5js.org/PragyaKumari2/sketches/3fhigQjLg");
}

function draw() {
  background(100, 200, 300);

  if (scene == 1) {
    image(img, 0, 0, 800, 600);
    text(
      "Read the options out loud and choose your answer, make sure to check the console for BARB's reply!",
      10,
      620
    );
    textSize(19);
    if (keyIsPressed) {
      if (key == 2) {
        scene = 2;
        ButtonA.remove();
        ButtonB.remove();
        ButtonC.remove();
        ButtonD.show();
        ButtonE.show();
        ButtonF.show();
      }
    }
  }

  if (scene == 2) {
    image(img2, 0, 0, 800, 600);
    text("Read the options loudly and choose your answer!", 50, 620);
    textSize(20);

    if (keyIsPressed) {
      if (key == 3) {
        scene = 3;
        ButtonD.remove();
        ButtonE.remove();
        ButtonF.remove();
        ButtonG.show();
        ButtonH.show();
        ButtonI.show();
      }
    }
  }
  if (scene == 3) {
    image(img3, 0, 0, 800, 600);
    text("Read the options loudly and choose your answer!", 50, 620);
    textSize(20);

    if (keyIsPressed) {
      if (key == 4) {
        scene = 4;
        ButtonG.remove();
        ButtonH.remove();
        ButtonI.remove();
        ButtonJ.show();
        ButtonK.show();
        ButtonL.show();
      }
    }
  }
  if (scene == 4) {
    image(img4, 0, 0, 800, 600);
    text("Read the options loudly and choose your answer!", 50, 620);
    textSize(20);

    if (keyIsPressed) {
      if (key == 5) {
        scene = 5;
        ButtonJ.remove();
        ButtonK.remove();
        ButtonL.remove();
        ButtonM.show();
        ButtonN.show();
        ButtonO.show();
      }
    }
  }
  if (scene == 5) {
    image(img5, 0, 0, 800, 600);

    text("Read the options loudly and choose your answer!", 50, 620);
    textSize(20);

    if (keyIsPressed) {
      if (key == 6) {
        scene = 6;
        ButtonM.remove();
        ButtonN.remove();
        ButtonO.remove();
        homebutton.show();
      }
    }
  }

  if (scene == 6) {
    text("Thanks a lot for playing! Make sure to practice speaking!", 200, 375);
    textSize(20);
  }

  textAlign(CENTER);
  text(msg, width / 2, height / 2);
}
```